# I need help graphing a spherical equation in Cartesian coordinates in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, cartesian-coordinates

I know about the function `sph2cart`, but I feel like I must be using it wrong. In a Calculus textbook, I saw that this following spherical equation:

```
ρ = 1 + 1/5*sin(6θ)*sin(5Φ)
```

produces something that looks like this:

[image: Bumpy Sphere]

I wanted to reproduce this in a Matlab graph, so I wrote the following code

```
 [q,t] = meshgrid(linspace(0,pi,100),linspace(0,2*pi,100));
 rho = 1+1/5*sin(6*t)*sin(5*q);
 [x,y,z] = sph2cart(t,q,rho);
 surf(x,y,z)
 axis square, axis equal
```

And I got the following graph:

[image: Not quite so bumpy as spiky]

Why is this happening? Why am I not getting the bumpy sphere my calc textbook shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You need .* rather than * between your sin(6*t) and sin(5*q) since you want per element multiplication not matrix multiplication.
2. You want q to run from 0-PI and t to run from 0-2PI

This code produces the result you're looking for.

```
[q,t] = meshgrid(linspace(0,2*pi,100),linspace(0,pi,100));
rho = 1+(1/5*sin(6*t).*sin(5*q));
[x,y,z] = sph2cart(t,q,rho);
surf(x,y,z)
axis square, axis equal
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure why? Your code "pre-amplified" 100x the Radius-axis basal constant value ( a 100 instead of 1 ) in contrast to the variable part, composing the "sperical surface" in the spherical coordinate system { Radius, Theta, Phi } --- it does not seem to have happened just by an accident Dave :o) [+1] for such remark. May try to add a UI-slider for such pre-amplification value ( make the "constant" a user-modify-able variable ) to see the effect live, in real-time GUI.

Comment: You're quite right :-)  On further consideration I realised the error in the OP's code was that the values of rho being calculated were way out of range and I noticed the matrix multiplication. Updated my answer to reflect this.