# Bumpy and wrinkled Spheres in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, trigonometry, figure, surface

I'm trying to surface bumpy spheres and wrinkled spheres in Matlab using 
p = 1 + 0,2 * sin(phi * m) * sin(teta * n)

```
    teta = 0:6.23;
    phi = 0:3.14;
    [teta,phi] = meshgrid(teta, phi);
    figure, hold on
    for m = 1:12
        for n = 1:12
            p = 1 + 0.2*sin(m*teta).*sin(n*phi);
            surf(teta,phi,p)
            pause(0.05)
            clf('reset')
        end
    end
```

But it's not drawing any sphere just surfaces...what am I doing wrong and what should I change :)  Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Well, you're passing spherical coordinates to `surf` which only handles cartesian coordinates. Convert them first.

Comment: how should I do that @Suever ....I'm pretty new to matlab...could you help me with this please? :)

Comment: maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089707/i-need-help-graphing-a-spherical-equation-in-cartesian-coordinates-in-matlab) can be useful

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your example so I created a new one:

```
%We define the spherical coordinates.
theta   = linspace(0,2*pi,50);
phi     = linspace(0,pi,50);
[x1,x2] = meshgrid(linspace(0,12*pi,50),linspace(0,12*pi,50)); %the variation of rho will produce a bumpy sphere.
rho     = 0.1*(sin(x1)+cos(x2))+1;
[theta,phi] = meshgrid(theta,phi);

%we calculate the cartesian coordinates.
x   =   rho.*cos(theta).*sin(phi);
y   =   rho.*sin(theta).*sin(phi);
z   =   rho.*cos(phi);

%plot   
surf(x,y,z);
```

**RESULT BUMPY**

[image]

**RESULT WRINKLED**

Simply change the rho parameter by:

```
rho     = 0.1*(sin(x1))+1;
```

[image]